# Quarkus Apache CXF Project fails to build with wsdl2java

Tags: cxf, quarkus

I am trying to build a simple Apache CXF project in Quarkus, using the following web site for instructions:

https://quarkiverse.github.io/quarkiverse-docs/quarkus-cxf/dev/user-guide/first-soap-web-service.html

I am using Quarkus 2.16.6, and only included the extension quarkus-cxf.  By default Quarkus adds the extension with version 1.7.3. The project is empty. When building, it does not recognize the following configuration parameter to convert SOAP WSDLs to Java:

quarkus.cxf.codegen.wsdl2java.includes = wsdl/*.wsdl

It returns the following warning:

[WARNING] [io.quarkus.config] Unrecognized configuration key "quarkus.cxf.codegen.wsdl2java.includes" was provided; it will be ignored; verify that the dependency extension for this configuration is set or that you did not make a typo

To fix this I removed the version of the quarkus extension and added the following BOM statement in pom.xml according to the web site instructions:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>io.quarkiverse.cxf</groupId>
  <artifactId>quarkus-cxf</artifactId>
  <version>2.0.0.CR1</version>
</dependency>
```

When I do this and try to do a build, it recognizes the configuration parameter but I get a build failure:

[ERROR]         [error]: Build step io.quarkiverse.cxf.deployment.QuarkusCxfProcessor#bus threw an exception: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: jakarta/annotation/Resource

How to fix this?  It looks like the issue is with a dependency contained in wsdl2java

Comment: You likely need to use Quarkus 3 with that version of the CXF extension

Comment: Yes looks like wsdl2java has a jakarta dependency which is only in Quarkus 3.  I tried it and the issue is gone. With 2.16 I had to do this in a separate Apache CXF project and import the pojos from there.

Answer (score 0):

The embedded Apache wsdl2java has a jakarta dependency which is only supported in Quarkus 3.0.  The only way to do this in Quarkus 2.x is to generate the wsdl pojos using a separate project via Apache CXF 3.x